# Kamatz Katan Question

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, vowels-nekudot

Can someone kindly confirm if שׁלוֹמָךְ and אַמָךְ have a kamatz katan in them? I do not believe they do, but I’m still working on my ability to spot the kamatz katan in some words.

I would pronounce these as shel-o-ma-ch and a-ma-ch, rather than with the “o” sound of the kamatz katan.

Comment: Where did you find these words?

Comment: They appear in Siddur Eretz Yisrael (http://www.moresheteretzhatzvi.co.il/קנה%20עכשיו.html)

Comment: Since they are accented syllables, I'd hardly believe...

Comment: I believe the answers at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38541 should suffice for you.

Comment: Thanks for the resources! Is the consensus no kamatz katan in these words?